# Need a python script to search specific keywords in a collection of sql files returning the index of where each keyword was found

Tags: python, sql, search

I'm extremely new to python and I was just wondering how could I take a collection of files (sql), and using some specific keywords, find which line of code they are matched throughout all the files. Any notions, ideas or suggestions would be life savingly helpful.

Kind Regards

Tiago M

Comment: Does it have to be Python? Can you `grep -n` for the keyword instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution

```
s = 'somestring'
names = ['file1.sql', 'file2.sql']
for n in names:  
    f = open(n)
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i, l in enumerate(lines):
        if s in l:
            print 'line %d' % (i)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to look at the `os.walk` function then `open` each file and use `in`, `string.find`, or `re.search` on the lines of each file.  For example:

```
search_term = "where x > 1"
for directory, subdirectories, paths in os.walk("/path/to/sql_directory"):
    for path in paths:
        f = open(path, "r")
        for line_no, line in enumerate(f):
             if search_term in line: # could use re module functions here
                 print "%s(%d): %s"%(path, line_no, line)
```